# DataTable to JSON- lose extra formatting?

Tags: json, wcf, datatable

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but I've read dozens of articles and pages with no joy. I need to pass a DataTable from a windows service to an asp.net page. It seemed that serializing to Json seemed a good idea, so I have this:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "DataGrabber")]
    public interface IDataGrabber
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="GET", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/Tables/{tablename}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(string tablename);
    }


public class DataGrabber : IDataGrabber
    {

        public string GetData(string TableName)
        {
            DataTable result;

            switch (TableName)
            {
                case "firstTable":
                    result = Grabber.firstTable;
                    break;
                //SNIP MORE 
            }


            return GetJson(result);
        }

        public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
              new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

And my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="DataGrabber">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/DataGrabber"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" name="Rest"
        contract="DataGrabber.IDataGrabber" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This works OK, but my resulting JSON has lots of escaped quotes, like this:

> "[{\"lat\":51.75,\"lng\":-1.25,\"score\":7},{\"lat\":31.780001,\"lng\":35.23,\"score\":7},{\"lat\":47.717999,\"lng\":-116.951599,\"score\":9},{\"lat\":33.990799,\"lng\":-118.460098,\"score\":1},{\"lat\":34.746498,\"lng\":-92.289597,\"score\":10},{\"lat\":-31.9522,...

This is rejected by online parsers, and won't serialize back to a DataTable in my client application. If I strip out all the extra stuff by using the "htmlviewer" instead of "textviewer" while debugging in VS, it's fine for the parsers. I tried using the Newtonsoft library too, and it resulted in similar output- so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical. Straight after posting I found the answer.

So because I was converting to a string, it was getting double encoded. Instead, I needed to output a stream.

So both my interface and method are now set to return a System.IO.Stream, and the output is generated thus:

```
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetJson(result)));
```